# Bubble sort with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, synchronized

I have a school assignment where Iam going to use threads in Java to sort a long name list. There is no focus on the speed of the sorting algorithm, but a assignment for understanding threads and how threads affect the speed of the sort.

I feel I'm on the right path, but the code/threads messes up the monitor, I have tried for a while to locate the problem, for me the problem seems to be in `class SortThreads` `run()` method. Can folks please give me some tips or hints?

```
public void run() {

    while (monitor.getSize() > 1) {
        System.out.println("Number of array in list to be sorted: "
                + monitor.getSize());

        String[] f = monitor.getRandom();
        String[] g = monitor.getRandom();

        monitor.add(descSort(f, g));
    }

    System.out.println("*** THREAD DEAD ***");

}
```

Output:

```
After delete: 1
Number of array in list to be sorted: 3
Befor delete: 1
After delete: 0
Number of array in list to be sorted: 0
Exception in thread "Thread-101" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SortThread.append(Sort.java:222)
    at SortThread.descSort(Sort.java:201)
    at SortThread.run(Sort.java:178)
Exception in thread "Thread-96" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SortThread.append(Sort.java:222)
    at SortThread.descSort(Sort.java:201)
    at SortThread.run(Sort.java:178)
Number of array in list to be sorted: 0
Number of array in list to be sorted: 0
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant part of the code. I'm not about to do data mining on this post to find where the `run` method is.

Comment: You are going to have to show more work then just posting a _large_ bunch of code.  What debugging have you done?  What output are you seeing?

Comment: We might be able to provide some hints but please elaborate first: in what way does it mess up?

Comment: Are your constrained to use Bubble Sort? Not only is it a bad sorting algorithm, it's also not the most prone to parallelization. Why don't you try quicksort or merge sort instead?

Comment: Also... does it have to be bubble sort? It's not really an algorithm that lends itself to multi-threading. Merge sort is much better suited.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I will rewrite the sort algorithm to merge sort. But I cant see how merge sort will make the thread to corporate correctly ?

Comment: My code is actually working, the result file contains alle the word correctly sorted, yet with error messages. If I try to sort 12 names with 128 threads, no result is produced.

Comment: @user265767: Merge sort is much easier to parallelize. All you have to do is launch one thread for each of the two recursive calls and implement a simple mechanism to control the recursion depth such that you don't oversubscribe the system. Let me know if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your (possible) problems is that this section is not atomic:

```
while (monitor.getSize() > 1) {
    System.out.println("Number of array in list to be sorted: "
            + monitor.getSize());

    String[] f = monitor.getRandom();
    String[] g = monitor.getRandom();

    monitor.add(descSort(f, g));
}
```

Typically, if you use any threads, it is very likely that between the call to `monitor.getSize()` and `monitor.getRandom()` the size has actually changed. So I guess that one of the `getRandom` calls (or both) returns null which triggers the `NullPointerException`.

You could add a check for `null` before calling `descSort()`. If only one of `f` and `g` is `null`, you probably need to put it back into the monitor (just guessing here).

Comment: Thats correct, checking for null and break; inside while loop when f or g are null eliminates NullPointerExceptions, and creates a correct sorted array. But when f or g is null, there is nothing to add to the container, because g and f are null, correct ?

Comment: To be honest I have not looked at the details of your code. Why don't you run some tests to make sure the output is as expected?